# Remove historical Stored Procedures from SQL Server backup

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

A developer has included a DB password within a stored procedure (rolls eyes). We include a backup of this database with our setup application for new customers. We've updated the stored procedure, but the password is still visible in plain text within the backup file as this includes both the current stored procedure *and* the original one.

We've cleared transaction history and recreated the log file, but these don't seem to affect historical stored procedure code. Is there some way of removing this from the DB backup?

Thanks *very much* in advance for any suggestions! We've hunted around and drawn a blank so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could re-create the full db. SSMS will support you under Tasks -> Generate Scripts... But this can be quite a big work to do...

If you are developing with Visual Studio You could think about a data base project to set your database under Source Control and get a scripted master. This makes it easier to re-create the full database and offers many other benefits. Other IDEs will support this too - probably.

You could try to set the db to single-user-mode, set its backup mode to simple, shrink the log file to smallest, shrink database files to smallest and drive a full backup. I've never had this problem, but I'd assume, that doing so, all residues should disappear...

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. We've tried all these options now, but still no luck.

Comment: @DavidClark, If you re-create the full db from scripts you still find the password within your db? Then it must be found within your scripts too. Maybe it is on another place you did not think of before... One more idea: You could create your SPs and UDFs encrypted

Comment: We're trying the approach of using scripts to recreate the DB now thanks. That does at least hide the old SP revisions. We're just now picking through the data migration errors... Thanks very much for your help.